# Modified double slit experiment with single entangled particle

Tags: quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment

Say we use one of the entangled particle (A) for the experiment, if we measure the other particle (B) would particle (A) still be able to exhibit interference pattern since physically only the experimentor is aware?

Comment: Why would it not show interference patterns? There are no particles A and B, by the way, only observers A and B that measure quanta of the same quantum field at $x_A$ and $x_B$. To observer A the quanta are still quanta, he simply doesn't know about their spin or phase values being correlated with some other point in space. The field will show the same kind of interference whether that correlation exists, or not.

Comment: *which slit* and *polarity* aren't commuting observables. If you look for 2 commuting o. and optimize the experiment, you will come back to EPR

Comment: @CuriousOne: sorry I meant to ask will the wave function of A collapsed when observer B performed the measurement on "one photon universe" or whatever that means, I just learnt my mistake that with time interference pattern will show up regardless.

Comment: The collapse of the wavefunction is an old concept that basically doesn't mean anything else than that the Born rule applies to certain types of strong measurements. It's not a physical effect or event. Since there are no waves and particles here, there is also no need to talk about the collapse of the wavefunction. Different observers can measure quanta with certain probabilities and sometimes these probabilities are correlated (that's entanglement). This has absolute no impact on the meaning of "quantum" or the physical behavior of the quantum field.